# Foundation 5 sections

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm having some issues with sections in Foundation 5.

```
<div class="section-container horizontal-nav" data-section="horizontal-nav">
<section>
<p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
<div class="content" data-section-content>
  <ul class="side-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The above code only yields a vertical list, not the horizontal that the code is supposed to trigger. The code works in 4 but not in 5. I assume its a javascript change but the 5 documentation doesn't mention sections and the side-nav documentation mentions nothing about the section-container classes. Anybody get this to work in 5 yet?

Comment: I think they have removed support for Sections in version 5 of Foundation (tabs and accordians are still there however - refer to the section of the documentation entitled Content at: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/).

Comment: Indeed, it was removed in v5. Replace them with the tabs, then style your tabs to add the grey lines. 
in your sass file:
`.tabs{
 border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
 dd.active{
  border:1px solid #ddd !important;
  border-bottom-color:white !important;
 } 
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar using top-bar in a class="large-12 columns" (or whatever number of columns you want). All you have to do is take care of the menu styles if you want it to look different from the classic top-bar.

Here's a simple example, is not too fancy but hopefully it'll help to get started:

```
<header class="row">

  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" role="navigation" data-options="is_hover:false">
    <!-- All your menu code here -->
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdwo3aLc/embedded/result/